# Is my proof of $p\to q\vdash \lnot p\lor q$ correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

Here is my way of natural deduction but I don't really know if it is an okay proof:

> 1. $p\to q$, premise
>
>    > 2. $\lnot(\lnot p\lor q)$, assumed
>    >
>    >    > 3. $\lnot q$, assumed
>    >    > 4. $\lnot (\lnot p), ~~\lor e_{2,3}$
>    >    > 5. $p, ~~~~~~~~~~~\lnot\lnot e_4$
>    >    > 6. $q, ~~~~~~~~~~\to{e_{1,5}}$
>    >    > 7. $\bot ~~~~~~~~~~~\bot i_{3,6}$
>    > 3. $q ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\lnot i_{3,7}$
>    > 4. $\lnot p\lor q ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\lor{i_8} $
>    > 5. $\bot ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\bot i_{2,9}$
> 2. $\lnot p\lor q ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\lnot e_{2,10}$

Thanks in advance, I am open for any criticism.

**EDIT:** line numbers are messed up, they are supposed to be 1 to 11.

Comment: How you derive 4 from 2 and 3 ? $\lor$-elim "acts on" $p \lor q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Since I assumed $\lnot q$ on 3, $q$ in 2 does not have any purpose so I eliminated it, hence $\lnot (\lnot p)$. Is it not possible?

Comment: I'm assuming that $\lor$e is [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In 3 you have to assume $\lnot p$ and then derive $\lnot p \lor q$ by $\lor$i. This is used to contradict 2.

Comment: Ah, you are right. That turned out to be a good solution, thank you!